# Does node.js shell have commands like python type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, node.js, shell

I want to know whether a object is null or undefined so I use the following code:

```
if(obj==='undefined'||obj===null)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there similar python type command to get the type of obj in node.js shell? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you're looking for `typeof`: `typeof(foo)` --> "undefined"

Comment: Indeed. ```obj==='undefined'``` assumes that ```obj``` is a string with the value of ```undefined```.

Comment: Underscore.js has some handy functions to check for variable types (`isNull` and `isUndefined` in your case), but nothing can substitute learning Javascript of course :).

Comment: also in python you should not be using `type`, you should be using `isinstance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> typeof foo == 'undefined'
true
> typeof 1 == 'number'
true
```

This should work for you:

```
if( typeof obj === 'undefined' || obj === null)
```

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

> The `typeof` operator returns a string indicating the type of the
>   unevaluated operand.